# Using COUNTIF inside aggregation function

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, sum, window-functions

Im making a betting system app. I need to count the points of a user based on his bets, knowing that some of the bets can be 'combined', which makes the calcul a bit more complex than a simple addition.

So if i have 3 bets: {points: 3, combined: false}, {points: 5, combined: true}, {points: 10, combined: true}, there are **two** bets combined here, so the total points should be 3 + (5 * **2**) + (10 * **2**). *Reality is a bit more complex since the points are not directly in the bet object but in the match it refers to*

Here is a part of my query. As you can see, i first check if the bet is right based on the match result, in that case if the bet is combined I multiply it by the value of combinedLength, else i'll just sum the value of that bet. I tried to replicate the COUNTIF inside the CASE, which gaves me an error like 'cannot aggregation inside aggregation'.

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.userId') AS userId,
  COUNTIF(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.combined') = 'true') AS combinedLength,
  SUM (
    (
      CASE WHEN JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.value') = match.result
      THEN IF(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.combined') = "true", match.odd * combinedLength, match.odd)
      ELSE 0 
      END
    )
  ) AS totalScore,
FROM data.user_bets_raw_latest
INNER JOIN matchLines ON matchLines.match.matchId = JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.fixtureId')
GROUP BY userId
```

I've been looking for days... thanks so much for the help !

Comment: Please show sample of input data and expected result. See how to present [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, then you need to count the total number of combined bets per user in a subquery, using a window function. Then, you can use this information while aggregating.

Consider:

```sql
select 
    user_id,
    sum(case when combined = 'true' then odd * cnt_combined else odd end) total_score
from (
    select
        u.*,
        m.match.odd,
        countif(b.combined = 'true') over(partition by userid) as cnt_combined,
    from (
        select 
            json_extract_scalar(data, '$.userid')    userid,
            json_extract_scalar(data, '$.combined')  combined,
            json_extract_scalar(data, '$.value')     value,
            json_extract_scalar(data, '$.fixtureid') fixtureid
        from data.user_bets_raw_latest
    ) b
    left join matchlines m 
        on  m.match.matchid = b.fixtureid
        and m.match.result  = b.value
) t
group by userid
```

I find that it is simpler to use a `left join` and put the condition on the match result in there.

I moved the json extractions to a subquery to reduce the length of the query.

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution :) 
I ended up doing it a bit differently, by creating an other 'tables' (with WITH) to organize my combined data and to calculate my score. I wasn't aware i could achieve the same thing with OVER and PARTITION BY. It's good to know ! Sorry for the late reply !